# How to connect three squares in ion-grid with CSS or SVG?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, svg, ionic3

I have an `ion-grid` of 1 row by 3 columns:

What I'd like to do is connect the green squares with a dashed line, like this (the line is hand drawed on the image):

[image]
[image]

I have thought to put a background image of a dashed line behind the grid, but this is what I get:
[image]

When the grid is vertically positioned, the line should be vertical, and the same with horizontal position (like in the first images).

Also, I have thought of a SVG dashed line drawed somehow between the squares (but I'm very new to SVG so I'm not very sure).

Could this be achived by using HTML, CSS or SVG? Can you think of anything different?

**Edit: added code**

Current HTML:

```
<div class="my-grid">
    <ion-grid fixed>
        <ion-row text-center>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
                <div></div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
                <div></div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
                <div></div>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</div>
```

Current CSS:

```
ion-col div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
ion-col {
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;

    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

**Edit: added Stackblitz example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-m2uzug).**

Comment: can you post a bit of code you have now for this dashed line?

Comment: Yeah! I forgot it, but just edited my question.

Comment: can you add css to your stackblitz please so i can edit there?

Comment: The CSS file (`home.scss`) should be inside `pages/home/` directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining the grid areas for grind items, you can achieve overlapping items and thus add a dashed line. See my snippet below.

```css
ion-row {
  display: grid;
}
ion-col div {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
ion-col {
    border-width: thin;
    border-color: blue;
    border-style: solid;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

@media (min-width: 577px) {
ion-row {
  grid-template-columns: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-template-rows: 150px;
}
ion-col {
  grid-row: 1;
}
ion-col:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1;
}
ion-col:nth-child(2) {
  grid-column: 2;
}
ion-col:nth-child(3) {
  grid-column: 3;
}
.dash-container {
  grid-column: 1 / 4;
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 3px;
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.dash.horizontal {
  width: 66%;
  border-top: 3px dashed #000;
  height: 10px;
}
} 
@media (max-width: 576px) {
ion-row {
  grid-template-rows: 33% 33% 33%;
  grid-template-columns: 150px;
  height: 450px;
}
ion-col {
  grid-column: 1;
}
ion-col:nth-child(1) {
  grid-row: 1;
}
ion-col:nth-child(2) {
  grid-row: 2;
}
ion-col:nth-child(3) {
  grid-row: 3;
}
.dash-container {
  grid-row: 1 / 4;
  grid-column: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  align-self: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 33%;
}
.dash.horizontal {
  height: 66%;
  border-left: 3px dashed #000;
  width: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid">
    <ion-grid fixed>
        <ion-row text-center>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
                <div></div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
                <div></div>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col-12 col-sm>
                <div></div>
            </ion-col>
            <div class="dash-container">
              <div class="dash horizontal"></div>
            </div>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</div>
```

I have added a new element `.dash-container` which spans the whole grid and is self-centered. Within that element is another element which is only 66% in width/height (which is the distance between the center points of the outer boxes if each is 33% wide) and has a dashed border.

I combined both former snippets into one using media queries. Below 577px, the grid is vertical.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It works pretty well. But do you know how CSS should be if the grid were positioned vertically (imagine it is always vertical, with the same HTML, forget responsiveness)? I have been playing with `display`, `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows` properties and also with `.dash-container` and `.dash-horizontal` classes, with no luck. I had to comment out `display: grid` in order to see the dash line and, even, I have tried `transform: rotate(90deg)` to make the line vertical.

Comment: I added a vertical example as well.

Comment: Thank you so much. Works perfect. I see the swapping between columns and rows. Just in case someone has the same problem, I've needed to replace `ion-row` selector with `.row` selector because `display: grid` wasn't been applied.

Comment: And to make it responsive I used media queries like: `@media (min-width: 577px) {}` for horizontal CSS and `@media (max-width: 576px) {}` for vertical CSS.

Comment: I edited my answer to combine both snippets into one also using media queries.